# Closure in predicates with delegates unknown at compile-time

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, closures, predicate

I have a following scenario:

A method that gets the list of people from a certain class that are shorter than some height threshold. I am using Where extension method to filter them out. Since the predicate depends on some external data, `classId` and `height` variables become a part of the lambda closure.

```
public List<Person> getPeopleFromClassShorterThanLimit(int classId, int height)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    return db.Persons.Where(p => p.Height <= height && p.ClassId == classId).ToList();
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the predicate gets complicated so I want to extract it to another method:

```
public List<Person> getPeopleFromClassLowerThanLimit(int classId, int height)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    return db.Persons.Where(isLowerThan).ToList();
}

private bool isLowerThan(Person person)
{

}
```

However, the closure here becomes the problem, because I can't pass the variables to the predicate function. I can make a delegate function inline (not using lambdas) so that the predicate looks like a function, but then this function must also be in the same method as the `Where()` call. In most of the scenarios it's ok, **but sometimes I want an external function (unknown at compile time) to be called as the `Where` predicate**.

The closest I came to the solution is this:

```
public delegate bool ExtendedPredicate<T, TArg>(T argument, TArg[] arguments);

public static class Extended
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T, TArg>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, ExtendedPredicate<T, TArg> predicate, params TArg[] arguments)
    {
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            if (predicate(item, arguments))
                yield return item;
        }

        yield break;
    }
}

public List<Person> getPeopleFromClassShorterThanLimit(int classId, int height)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    return db.Persons.Where(isFromClassShorterThanLimit, classId, height).ToList();
}

public bool isFromClassShorterThanLimit(Person person, int[] arguments)
{
    return person.Height <= arguments[0] && person.ClassId == arguments[1];
}
```

but I find it somewhat too narrow and also, for each extension method a new overload would have to be written. In addition to all that, I guess the EntityFramework would not be able to convert such expressions into a reasonable SQL statement (not sure about this, I am no expert in how EF generates SQL from lambdas, but that's a wild guess). 
*(variable number of arguments may or may not be provided)*

**Question:**

What I'd like know to is whether there is any smart way of achieving this with regular delegates (not forcing compile-time defined functions to be used as a predicate) without such hacks as one shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
public List<Person> getPeopleFromClassLowerThanLimit(int classId, int height)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    return db.Persons.Where(p => isLowerThan(p, classId, height)).ToList();
}

private bool isLowerThan(Person person, int classId, int height)
{

}
```

Comment: Now that I think of it, I made a complex thing out of a simple thing. In a sense, I need this to work even with a variable number of closure variables, so array would be ok, but it is true that I don't need to extend the Where method. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Glad it helped. Even I don't know what you were thinking, i.e., I don't understand `Delegates` very well and was not able to grok the code sample. Which is probably why I was able to identify the simpler solution :)

Comment: Well, the code in my "solution" was just an attempt to avoid having lambda as predicate. But I failed to realize that there's nothing wrong with the lambda if by calling a delegate within the lambda I can reach that external method I wanted as a predicate in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call your method as predicate of the normal where method:

```
public List<Person> getPeopleFromClassShorterThanLimit(int classId, int height)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    return db.Persons.Where(x=>isFromClassShorterThanLimit(classId, height)).ToList();
}
```